# How to merge adjacent, similar entries of a sorted `Stream` or `List`

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Given a

- large ( > 1,000,000 entries, don't expect it to fit into memory)
- sorted (wrt. the first value of the tuple)

stream like

```
val ss = List( (1, "2.5"), (1, "5.0"), (2, "3.0"), (2, "4.0"), (2, "6.0"), (3, "1.0")).toStream
// just for demo
val xs = List( (1, "2.5"), (1, "5.0"), (2, "3.0"), (2, "4.0"), (2, "6.0"), (3, "1.0"))
```

I want to join adjacent entries such that the output of transformation becomes

```
List( (1, "2.5 5.0"), (2, "3.0 4.0 6.0"), (3, "6.0") )
```

The second tuple value is to be merged by some monoid function (string concatenation here)

### Ideas / attempts / tries

#### groupBy

`groupBy` does not seem to be a valid alternative, as entries are collected in a map *in memory*.

#### scanLeft

```
val ss: Stream[(Int, String)] = List( (1, "2.5"), (1, "5.0"), (2, "3.0")).toStream

val transformed = ss.scanLeft(Joiner(0, "a"))( (j, t) => {
  j.x match {
    case t._1 => j.copy(y = j.y + " " + t._2)
    case _ => Joiner(t._1, t._2)
  }
})
println(transformed.toList)
```

which ends up in

```
List(Joiner(0,a), Joiner(1,2.5), Joiner(1,2.5 5.0), Joiner(2,3.0))
```

(please ignore wrapping `Joiner`)

but I didn't find a way to get rid of the "incomplete" entries.

Comment: Wrt second approach: I want `List( Joiner(1,2.5 5.0), Joiner(2,3.0) )`. The entry `Joiner(1,2.5)` is what I call incomplete. And `Joiner(0,a)` is just the start point.

Comment: Consider returning a tuple, e.g. `(Jointer, Boolean)` with the second element indicating whether this is the "final" entry. Then `.collect { case(j,true) => j}`

Comment: @Dima: Nice try (that I also had in mind, but I didn't want to use a flag but a second case class instead). Still, I failed with this approach, as I did not find a way how to *see*  if an entry is completed. Could you please sketch the code ....

Answer (score 1):

Emit `true` to indicate the *initial* element (when the value switches), not the *final* one, that's easy, right? Then you can just collect those entries, that are followed by the initial one. 
Something like this perhaps:

```
   ss.scanLeft((0, "", true)) { 
     case ((a, str, _), (b, c)) if (str == "" || a == b) => (b, str + " " + c, false) 
     case (_, (b, c)) => (b, c.toString, true)
   } .:+ (0, "", true)
     .sliding(2)
     .collect { case Seq(a, (_, _, true)) =>  (a._1, a._2) }
```

(note the `.:+` thingy - it appends a "dummy" entry to the end of the stream, so that the last "real" element is also followed by the "true" entry, and does not get filtered out).

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do okay.

```
def makeEm(s: Stream[(Int, String)]) = {

  import Stream._

  @tailrec
  def z(source: Stream[(Int, String)], curr: (Int, List[String]), acc: Stream[(Int, String)]): Stream[(Int, String)] = source match {
    case Empty =>
      Empty
    case x #:: Empty =>
      acc :+ (curr._1 -> (x._2 :: curr._2).mkString(","))
    case x #:: y #:: etc if x._1 != y._1 =>
      val c = curr._1 -> (x._2 :: curr._2).mkString(",")
      z(y #:: etc, (y._1, List[String]()), acc :+ c)
    case x #:: etc =>
      z(etc, (x._1, x._2 :: curr._2), acc)
  }

  z(s, (0, List()), Stream())
}
```

Tests:

```
val ss = List( (1, "2.5"), (1, "5.0"), (2, "3.0"), (2, "4.0"), (2, "6.0"), (3, "1.0")).toStream
makeEm(ss).toList.mkString(",")

val s = List().toStream
makeEm(s).toList.mkString(",")

val ss2 = List( (1, "2.5"), (1, "5.0")).toStream
makeEm(ss2).toList.mkString(",")

val s3 = List((1, "2.5"),(2, "4.0"),(3, "1.0")).toStream
makeEm(s3).toList.mkString(",")
```

Output

```
ss: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[(Int, String)] = Stream((1,2.5), ?)
res0: String = (1,5.0,2.5),(2,6.0,4.0,3.0),(3,1.0)

s: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Nothing] = Stream()
res1: String = 

ss2: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[(Int, String)] = Stream((1,2.5), ?)
res2: String = (1,5.0,2.5)

s3: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[(Int, String)] = Stream((1,2.5), ?)
res3: String = (0,2.5),(2,4.0),(3,1.0)
```